# Trying to create a dynamic list in EXCEL

Tags: excel, function, dynamic-list

I am trying to create a dynamic list that returns a variable number of items.

I want to be able to enter a CLLI code in row M2 and have the associated PowerPlants be returned in cells M5 to M...

Can anyone help?

***Example:***
[image]

Comment: Is this similar, there are other questions about dynamic lists : https://stackoverflow.com/q/30247612/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would provide a simple answer here regarding the question. However, the answer to your question would be a bit lengthy. (Simple) but lengthy.
With that said, here is a link for quick, straightforward answer.

https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/dependent-drop-lists/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## ***Edit # 1***

Non array formula to get list. Put the formula in `M5` cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($K$2:$K$21,SMALL(INDEX((ROW($J$2:$J$21)-ROW($J$1))-($J$2:$J$21<>$M$2)*(1E+99)*-1,, ),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Use following array formula to `M5` cell and drag and down as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($K$2:$K$19,SMALL(IF($J$2:$J$19=$M$2,ROW($J$2:$J$19)-ROW($J$1),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

The Array formula needs to be added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering it in the cell.

[image]

Again, you *must* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after putting the formula in the cell.

Comment: [Data filter based on condition answer by me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967385/how-to-filter-data-based-on-condition-using-non-array-formula)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is always sorted by SitesCLLI as shown in your provided image, you can use this formula in cell M5 and copy down (regular formula, no array entry needed):

```
=IF(ROW(M1)>COUNTIF(J:J,M$2),"",INDEX(K:K,MATCH(M$2,J:J,0)+ROW(M1)-1))
```

Comment: Don't mind. I always prefer non array formula because array formula runs slow. You formula do not giving correct output if there more data in different row in `J:J` column. Can you please test it with my screenshot yellow highlighted data and ensure it is working?

Comment: @harun24hr "Assuming your data is always sorted by SitesCLLI as shown in your provided image"

Comment: [Non array approach to filter data based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967385/how-to-filter-data-based-on-condition-using-non-array-formula)   I have updated my answer which will filter data to non sorted array of data.